# Prove $\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^2\ge 2\sqrt{2\left(x+y\right)\sqrt{xy}}$, with $x,\:y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\ne 0$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

My thinking:

Starting with the basic fact $\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)^4\ge 0$ which is trivial.

$\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)^4\ge 0\:$

$\rightarrow \:x^2-4\sqrt{yx}\sqrt{x}+6xy-4\sqrt{xy}\sqrt{y}+y^2\ge \:0\:$

$\rightarrow x^2+4\sqrt{yx}\sqrt{x}+6xy+4\sqrt{xy}\sqrt{y}+y^2\ge \:8\sqrt{yx}\sqrt{x}+8\sqrt{xy}\sqrt{y}$

$\rightarrow $ $\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^4\ge \: \:8\sqrt{yx}\sqrt{x}+8\sqrt{xy}\sqrt{y}$

$\rightarrow \frac{\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^4}{8}\ge \sqrt{yx}\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{xy}\sqrt{y}$

$\rightarrow \:\frac{\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^4}{8}\ge x\sqrt{xy}+y\sqrt{xy}$

$\rightarrow \:\frac{\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^4}{4}\ge 2x\sqrt{xy}+2y\sqrt{xy}$

$\rightarrow \:\frac{\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^2}{2}\ge \sqrt{2x\sqrt{xy}+2y\sqrt{xy}}$

$\rightarrow \:\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^2\ge 2\sqrt{2x\sqrt{xy}+2y\sqrt{xy}}$ as needed. QED

I'm not sure if this is correct. If someone can provide some feedback that would be great!

Comment: Presumably you want $x,y\geq0,$ or do you really want to allow complex numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof works, but there is a much more direct proof.

First, just write $a=\sqrt x,b=\sqrt y$ and rewrite it as $$(a+b)^2\geq 2\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(2ab)}$$

Letting $u=a^2+b^2, v=2ab,$ use AM/GM:

$$\frac{u+v}{2}\geq\sqrt{uv}$$

---

That first step is important from an aesthetic point of view, as much as anything - all those square roots are hard on the eyes, and it is difficult to see what is going on.

If we were to prove AM/GM ourselves, we would, of course, square $u-v=(a-b)^2,$ and you will see quite a lot of your proof is just proving AM/GM for a special case.

Comment: I would've never of thought of this. I was trying to use AGM as well but couldn't figure out how to do it exactly. Can you briefly explain how you knew to take the steps to do it this way?

Comment: I just did the $a,b$ substitution, then there was only one square root, and so I thought AM/GM. But $(a+b)^2$ is not a sum, unless you expand it, as $a^2+2ab+b^2.$ @Yaya123

Comment: That makes sense, I think I need more practice with this. I'm new to proof writing. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The given inequality is equivalent to the $t\ge0$ case of
$$(t+1)^4\ge8t(t^2+1)\tag1$$
(Let $t=\sqrt{y/x}$.) Taking the difference in (1),
$$(t+1)^4-8t^3-8t=(t-1)^4,$$
which proves (1) for arbitrary $t.$

Comment: Very good! It is short and effective